# Filter documents using multiple fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection named **Project**. Below is the schema description for Project collection :

```
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    projectName: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    },

    licenceType: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      lowercase: true
    },

    location: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true,
      trim: true
    },

    description: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    },

    projectType: {
      type: String,
      default: 'public'
    },

    status: {
      type: String,
      default: 'open'
    },

    budget: {
      type: Number
    },

    duration: {
      type: Number
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
```

I want to fetch documents using these fields as filters. The fields are :

- licenceType
- location
- date (timestamp is made true in schema for this purpose)

I can use these three fields in any combination to fetch documents. There is a possibility that no filter is applied at all  in which case its a simple fetching of all the documents in the collection.

I know I can dynamically build query using **if--else if--else** but I wanted to know is there any other more efficient way of handling such queries rather than using if--else blocks. If there would have been five or more fields for filtering purpose, there would be so many combinations to check using if--else block.

Appreciate any kind of help!!Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I assume there's some external trigger which actually modifies the filter matrix (eg. a request from some UI). Mongoose [allows you to specify filter up-front in a form of an object](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/query_casting.html), take a look below:

```
const query = Project.find({
  licenceType: 'sometype',
  location: 'somelocation'
});
```

Clearly you can see this...

```
    {
      licenceType: 'sometype',
      location: 'somelocation'
    }
```

...is an object. So, I think you could re-build the filtering object each time filters change (create an empty object `let myFilters = {}` and extend it with your filters: `myFilters['licenceType'] = 'sometype'`) and pass `myFilters` to `find` function.

Comment: Marek thank you so much for your help , appreciate it!